# How to prevent mounting file system without booting (linux)?

Tags: linux, mount

We have an hdd with Linux, don't want to let others break into it with mounting and a live CD. I think maybe it is possible with password protecting grub. But we need all services and scripts (for example in init.d folder) be run. 
We don't want to encrypt all the disk.
Is it possible to help in this, plz?

Thanks!

Comment: As far as i understand you - you will protect some of your data on a Harddisk from beeing read by someone else who has local access to the same Computer and the Harddisk ??? - And you think you can do this by somehow prohibiting to mount this Drive? - I think it is the only Option to encript the whole disk - Maybe there is a thirdparty Application that can handle encription on a per Folder Base

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your machines have internal HHD's, and you would like to prevent unauthorized access by a user using a live-cd, is this correct?

If so, you should look into [whole-drive-encryption](http://www.symantec.com/drive-encryption). I know that ou said you do not want to encrypt the entire drive, but encryption I believe is going to be the only way to go here.

Instead of encrypting the entire HDD, you could partition it so that all of your secure files are on a seperate partition that will be encrypted, and another partition for less-secure files that will not be encrypted.

There is no way [that I know of] to password protect a HDD without encryption that will prevent a user on a live-cd from mounting the disk.

**Edit**

I DO NOT recommend doing this, however it is another possibility as proposed by a suggestion from the OP.

On any given storage device, the first 512 bytes of the drive are the MBR and Partition table. This is the part that defines all of the partitions on the drive.], and without it, the system has no idea what is where, and thinks the drive is unformatted.

A possibility would be to, in the shutdown scrip, after the drives have been unmounted, use `dd` to create a backup image of the MBR, and then `0` it. Again, on boot, restore that MBR just before the system mounts the drive.

The specifics of where the backup MBR will go, and where the script will run from you will need to determine yourself, as I have not done this before on boot.

To create a backup of the MBR

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/media/somewhere/mbr.bak bs=512 count=1
```

To 0 the MBR

```
dd if=/dev/null of/dev/sda bs=512 count=1
```

To restore the MBR

```
dd if=/dev/somewhere/mbr.bak of=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1
```

Again, be very cautious when doing this, and make sure you create a backup of your MBR on a USB drive with a live bootable OS so that you can restore it if it screws anything up.

The specifics of where in the shutdown script and bootup scrip will need to be figured out, as the MBR need to be read from a mounted drive, and it can not mount a drive with no MBR.

Comment: Yes, you understood me correctly. is there any way to change header of file system or MBR for preventing that?

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: Presumably the MBR trick can be bypassed if the attacker knows what you did, right?

Comment: Presumably yes, however without the MBR, the attacker would need to know the exacts sizes, locations, and formats of all the partitions.